# Add number inside several Input (Type=number) after button click

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, input

I have added a button to my application that adds value to `input type='number'` after click. Everything works fine, but numbers starts from **0 and not 1**.

How can I make it so after click number starts from **1**.

Here is the code and **Jsfiddle code**: https://jsfiddle.net/gLs374h0/

```
 var arr_example = [1];
  $("#btn1").click(function(){
    $.each (arr_example, function() {
      $( ".order-number" ).each(function(value) {
        $( this ).val(value);
      });
    });
  });

<div id="sortable">
  <h1 id='btn1'>Sort</h1>
  <div class="nested-fields">
    <input type="number" placeholder="sort order" class='order-number'>
  </div>

  <div class="nested-fields">
    <input type="number" placeholder="sort order" class='order-number'>
  </div>

  <div class="nested-fields">
    <input type="number" placeholder="sort order" class='order-number'>
  </div>

  <div class="nested-fields">
    <input type="number" placeholder="sort order" class='order-number'>
  </div>

  <div class="nested-fields">
    <input type="number" placeholder="sort order" class='order-number'>
  </div>

</div>
```

Comment: Please post some code which you have tried so far. So others can point you in right direction

Answer (score 1, accepted):

here you have a [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/gLs374h0/1/)

```
 var arr_example = [1];
  $("#btn1").click(function(){
    $.each (arr_example, function() {
      $( ".order-number" ).each(function(value) {
        $( this ).val(value+1);
      });
    });
  });
```

Comment: Thanks @edisoni.1337:)

Comment: If you want the numbers to start from 1 in your input types you can add min='1' property but this will change only the min number that user can change not the start value here in javascript code :) Vote up :D

Comment: Great ;) Vote up mine too hahah need that ;)